# How to remove table data shaking after coming tooltip message

Tags: javascript, html, css

After creating a table, when I implemented the Onclick text copier in table data, the Onclick text copier working well but the problem is after clicking on the table data tooltip message come, and then data shake right to left. In Laravel temple, I embedded this code in a big data table somewhere shaking somewhere not shaking. How can I solve this problem?

```js
function textCopied(el){
  var inp = document.createElement('input');
  document.body.appendChild(inp);
  inp.value = el.textContent;
  inp.select();
  document.execCommand('copy',false);
  inp.remove();
  var tt = el.parentNode.querySelector(".custom-tooltip");
  tt.style.display = "inline";
  setTimeout( function() {
      tt.style.display = "none";
  }, 1000);
};
```

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
}
.copy_button{
    background-color:#fff;
    border:0;
    outline:0;
    cursor:pointer;
    opacity:1;
    position:absolute;
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    z-index:9;
    border-radius:24px;
    }
.button-tooltip-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 16px;
    min-height: 30px;
}
#custom-tooltip {
    display: none;
    margin-left: 40px;
    padding: 5px 12px;
    background-color: #000000df;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #fff;
}
table tbody tr td{
    padding: 20px 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table>
      <thaed>
          <tr>
              <th>ID</th>
          </tr>
      </thaed>
      <tbody>
          <tr>
              <td>
                  <div class="button-tooltip-container">
                      <span title="Click to Copy" onclick="textCopied(this);" class="copy_button">94426</span>
                      <span class="custom-tooltip" id="custom-tooltip">copied!</span>
                  </div>
              </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>
                  <div class="button-tooltip-container">
                      <span title="Click to Copy" onclick="textCopied(this);" class="copy_button">94425</span>
                      <span class="custom-tooltip" id="custom-tooltip">copied!</span>
                  </div>
              </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>
                  <div class="button-tooltip-container">
                      <span title="Click to Copy" onclick="textCopied(this);" class="copy_button">94424</span>
                      <span class="custom-tooltip" id="custom-tooltip">copied!</span>
                  </div>
              </td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Position the tooltip absolutely, that way it's taken out of the textflow, and showing it doesn't have influence on the layout.

Comment: After giving #custom-tooltip position absolute, the problem has solved. Thanks, Teemu.